# Uber RequestButton onClickListener

Tags: android, api, uber-api

I am using [Uber android-api](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk) in my project.
On click of RequestButton it navigates the user to Uber App but I want to process some data before it navigates to Uber app. So for that, I want onClickListener of RequestButton.

I have already tried giving onClickListener directly on the object of requestButton then I get the event but it does not navigate to Uber App.

---

```
requestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
      @Override 
       public void onClick(View v) {

       }
});
```

Comment: Post the code you're using to navigate.

Comment: @piyush there is no code from my side that navigates to uber.Already onclick listener is there in Uber SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to call your own custom code **before** the RequestButton is clicked, i.e. it's OnClickListener callback method is called, you have to change the code of the RequestButton inside the rides-android-sdk.

Then in your activity you have to call the setCustomPreOnClickListener on the RequestButton object:

```
public void rideRequestButtonWithCustomPreOnClickListener() {
        RequestButton uberButtonBlack = (RequestButton) findViewById(R.id.uber_button_black);
        RequestButton uberButtonWhite = (RequestButton) findViewById(R.id.uber_button_white);

        RideParameters rideParameters = new RideParameters.Builder()
                .setProductId(UBERX_PRODUCT_ID)
                .setPickupLocation(PICKUP_LAT, PICKUP_LONG, PICKUP_NICK, PICKUP_ADDR)
                .setDropoffLocation(DROPOFF_LAT, DROPOFF_LONG, DROPOFF_NICK, DROPOFF_ADDR)
                .build();

        uberButtonBlack.setRideParameters(rideParameters);
        uberButtonWhite.setRideParameters(rideParameters);

        uberButtonBlack.setCustomPreOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Custom code for black button called before UberRequestButton's onClick() listener");
            }
        });

        uberButtonWhite.setCustomPreOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Custom code for white button called before UberRequestButton's onClick() listener");
            }
        });
    }
```

Another approach is to create a custom class:

```
package com.uber.sdk.android.rides.samples;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.uber.sdk.android.rides.RequestButton;

public class CustomUberRequestButton extends RequestButton implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = CustomUberRequestButton.class.getSimpleName();

    public CustomUberRequestButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomUberRequestButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomUberRequestButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Custom code before calling UberRequestButton's onClick() listener");

        // Explicitly need to call UberRequestButton onClick() listener
        super.onClick(v);
    }
}
```

and you use it like this:

```
/**
 * Please make sure you replace com.uber.sdk.android.rides.RequestButton
 * with com.uber.sdk.android.rides.samples.CustomUberRequestButton inside
 * the res/layout/activity_sample.xml file, otherwise you will get a ClassCastException.
 */
public void rideRequestButtonWithCustomSubclassOnClickListener() {
    CustomUberRequestButton uberButtonBlack = (CustomUberRequestButton) findViewById(R.id.uber_button_black);
    CustomUberRequestButton uberButtonWhite = (CustomUberRequestButton) findViewById(R.id.uber_button_white);

    RideParameters rideParameters = new RideParameters.Builder()
            .setProductId(UBERX_PRODUCT_ID)
            .setPickupLocation(PICKUP_LAT, PICKUP_LONG, PICKUP_NICK, PICKUP_ADDR)
            .setDropoffLocation(DROPOFF_LAT, DROPOFF_LONG, DROPOFF_NICK, DROPOFF_ADDR)
            .build();

    uberButtonBlack.setRideParameters(rideParameters);
    uberButtonWhite.setRideParameters(rideParameters);
}
```

With the custom class you can also set a custom preOnClickListener if you want to. See the rideRequestButtonWithCustomSubclassAndPreOnClickListener method in the above commits.

Answer (score 2):

@bitek was on the right track but here is the complete solution for overriding the RideRequestButton

```
public class CustomUberButton extends RideRequestButton implements 
 View.OnClickListener {
private View.OnClickListener internalListener;
private View.OnClickListener preClickListener;

public CustomUberButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomUberButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomUberButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public void setPreClickListener(OnClickListener preClickListener) {
    this.preClickListener = preClickListener;
}

@Override
public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable OnClickListener l) {
    // redirect the listener to us but keep the original listener registered by the original button to reuse later.
    internalListener = l;
    super.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    preClickListener.onClick(view);
    internalListener.onClick(view);
}
```

}

The above class can be used in xml

```
<com.example.android.takemehome.uber.CustomUberButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_uber"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    uber:ub__style="black" />
```

and the activity Looks like

```
mUberButton = (CustomUberButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_uber);
mUberButton.setPreClickListener(this);
```

In this case the activity implements View.OnClickListener as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a custom `RequestButton` if you want to process something that `Uber SDK` can't.